# instantiating and placing Game Object on scene at wrong position

Tags: unity-game-engine, gps, position, instantiation, gameobject

i am trying to make a `Unity app`, which will get real word `coordinates`, convert them to `Unity` coordinates and when i reach to the position, it must `instantiate` and put the object(sphere) on that position, the problem is that it creates the object, but it places only on my position- position where i am standing. here is my code.

```
  var gpsLat = GPSManager_NoCompass.Instance.latitude;

  var gpsLon = GPSManager_NoCompass.Instance.longitude;

  float latitude = 40.1967097f; // here should be my game object
  float longitude = 44.4802051f;// here should be my game object

    //here is the code to make unity coordinates
  var latOffset = (latitude - gpsLat) * degreesLatitudeInMeters;
  var lonOffset = (longitude - gpsLon) * GetLongitudeDegreeDistance(latitude);

   //placing the sphere
  transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(latOffset, 0, lonOffset);
  sphere.transform.position = transform.position;
  sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3, 3, 3);
  Instantiate(sphere, sphere.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

i guess the problem is in `transform position`,as latOffset and lonOfsset are what i need. any ideas what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment right now, so I am posting it as an answer.

change last part with this:

```
 //placing the sphere
  transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(latOffset, 0, lonOffset);
  var instantiatedSphere = Instantiate(sphere, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
  instantiatedSphere .transform.localScale = new Vector3(3, 3, 3);
```

Because with yours right now, you are assigning a position and scale to a Sphere that isn't there.

Comment: Not only is the position being assigned to an object that doesn't yet exist, the position isn't even being assigned to the sphere! `this.transform.position = this.transform.position + new Vector3(latOffset, 0, lonOffset); //not sphere.transform`

Answer (score 0):

This first line

```
transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(latOffset, 0, lonOffset);
```

moves the object this script is attached to!

The next one the prefab of your sphere

```
sphere.transform.position = transform.position;
sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(3, 3, 3);
```

which is probably not what you want.

You should rather do something like

```
var newSpehere = Instantiate(sphere, transform.position + new Vector3(latOffset, 0, lonOffset), Quaternion.identity);
newSphere.localScale = Vector3.one * 3;
```